# Off-Canvas Nav with Dropdown Accordions Clipping Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, off-canvas-menu

I'm using Foundation v5.5 and combined [two](https://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/jtdvf) [different](http://codepen.io/designsoutheast/pen/ZYERGo) js codes to create a usable off-canvas top navigation with dropdown accordions.

However, when any of the dropdown accordions are selected, the text is being clipped because the .offcanvas-top class's height is being specified by the JS, and I simply don't know enough JS to add 100px to the height of .offcanvas-top. Thoughts?

Here is a link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/tgelles/pen/JXXjXK) and the js in question (I'm using WordPress, hence the noConflict):

```
//offcanvas dropdown accordions
var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
    $s(".off-canvas-submenu").hide();
    $s(".off-canvas-submenu-call").click(function() {
         var icon = $s(this).parent().next(".off-canvas-submenu").is(':visible') ? '+' : '-';
         $s(this).parent().next(".off-canvas-submenu").slideToggle('fast');
         $s(this).find("span").text(icon);
    });

//Offcanvas menu
(function(w){
     var $z = jQuery.noConflict();
      var $container = $z('.offcanvas-top'),
                $cHeight = $z('.o-content').outerHeight();
            $z(document).ready(function() {
                buildCanvas();
            });

            function buildCanvas() {
                $z('<a class="blue_bg button" href="#" id="trigger">Explore KSAS +</a>').appendTo($container);

                $z('#trigger').bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $this = $z(this);
                    $container.toggleClass('active');
                    if($container.hasClass('active')) {
                        $container.height($cHeight);
                        $this.text('Hide -');
                    } else {
                        $container.height(50);
                        $this.text('Explore KSAS +');
                    }
                });

            }

            $z(window).resize(function() { //On Window resizeBy(
                $cHeight = $z('.o-content').outerHeight();
        console.log($cHeight);
            });


        })(this);
```

with a screenshot of the problem below:

Before: 
[image: off-canvas top nav default state]

Clipped text from active accordion:
[image: off-canvas top nav with collapsed accordion]

Comment: Is the issue supposed to happen in the CodePen too? I'm not seeing the issue in Chrome, but your pen is lacking items that are obviously in your screenshot. Please actually reproduce the issue on CodePen.

Comment: Wanted to keep the pen as simple as possible, but added as much additional markup to best fully reproduce the issue. See: http://codepen.io/tgelles/details/JXXjXK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get you close. I combined it all into function because I did not see the purpose of multiple `noConflict()`'s.

#### JS

```javascript
//Offcanvas menu
(function(w) {
  var $z = jQuery.noConflict();
  var $container = $z('.offcanvas-top');
  var $cHeightMax = $z('.o-content').outerHeight();
  console.log($cHeightMax);
  $z(".off-canvas-submenu").hide();
  var $cHeightMin = $z('.o-content').outerHeight();
  console.log($cHeightMin);
  $z(document).ready(function() {
    buildCanvas();
  });

  function buildCanvas() {
    $z(".off-canvas-submenu-call").click(function() {
      var icon = $z(this).parent().next(".off-canvas-submenu").is(':visible') ? '+' : '-';
      var $subMenu = $z(this).parent().next(".off-canvas-submenu");
      
      $z(this).find("span").text(icon);
      
      if ($subMenu.css('display') === 'none') {
        $container.height($cHeightMax);
        $subMenu.slideToggle('fast');
      } else {
        $container.height($cHeightMin);
        $subMenu.slideToggle('fast');
      }
      
    });

    $z('<a class="blue_bg button" href="#" id="trigger">Explore KSAS +</a>').appendTo($container);

    $z('#trigger').bind('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $z(this);
      $container.toggleClass('active');
      if ($container.hasClass('active')) {
        $container.height($cHeightMin);
       $z('.o-content').show();
        $this.text('Hide -');
      } else {
        $container.height(50);
        $z('.o-content').hide();
        $this.text('Explore KSAS +');
        $z(".off-canvas-submenu").hide();
        $z(".off-canvas-submenu-call span").text('+');
      }
    });

  }

  $z(window).resize(function() { //On Window resizeBy(
    $cHeight = $z('.o-content').outerHeight();
    console.log($cHeight);
  });

})(this);
```

I changed the CSS of `.o-content` to this:

#### CSS

```css
.o-content {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em 1em 2.5em;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! thank you so much!

here's the [updated pen](http://codepen.io/tgelles/pen/qZZxyW) for those interested